# How to get rid of the "overshoots" in the picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a filled triangle where one of the edges is curved.  When I do the "obvious" thing, I find that the curved edge overshoots the vertices at either end.

Here is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate [label=left:{$a$}] (a) at (5, -2);
  \coordinate [label=right:{$b$}] (b) at (9, -3);
  \coordinate [label=right:{$c$}] (c) at (9,0);
  \filldraw [line width=2pt, color=green!70!black, fill=green!15!white] (b) -- (a) to [out=20,in=250] (c) -- (b);
  \foreach \point in {a,b,c}
  \filldraw [color=green!70!black,fill=green!70!black] (\point) circle     (1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: triangle with overshoot]

As you can see in the figure, the edge overshoots the vertices at (a) and (c).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just replace `\begin{tikzpicture}` by `\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel]`.

Comment: @marmot Thanks -- it worked.  This might be a very simple question, but if you think (as I do) that it's a useful answer, please write it as an answer.

Comment: I have given this very answer already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439182/121799), so strictly speaking this question is a duplicate, but I would be very surprised if my answer was the first of this kind... ;-)

Comment: Would you mind if your question got closed as a duplicate? You could still accept @Milo's answer. (But I will not close without your permission.)

Comment: Please do, if you think that’s appropriate.  I did not find the earlier question.

Answer (score 4):

I think `line join=bevel` is what you're looking for.

As per Henri Menke's comment, it is better to finish off the path with `-- cycle`, this ensures the line join here is consistent with the rest of the corners. Of course, in this example the line joins are sufficiently covered by the circles, but it's still good practice :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=bevel]
  \coordinate [label=left:{$a$}] (a) at (5, -2);
  \coordinate [label=right:{$b$}] (b) at (9, -3);
  \coordinate [label=right:{$c$}] (c) at (9,0);
  \filldraw [line width=2pt, color=green!70!black, fill=green!15!white] (b) -- (a) to [out=20,in=250] (c) -- cycle;
  \foreach \point in {a,b,c}
  \filldraw [color=green!70!black,fill=green!70!black] (\point) circle     (1.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `-- cycle;` instead of `-- (b);`.